# Are there any words which use 'カ', the on-yomi of 何?

Tags: words, kanji, onyomi

I started finally learning kanji's readings not only meanings and words. And in two sources I use I see that 何's kun'yomi is なん、なに and on' is カ.

I've seen 何 in many words as

なん: 何度、何と、何で

なに: 何人、何か

ど: 何処、何の

何れ (いずれ)、何時(いつ)

- I know, that ど and い readings can be exceptions.

But never as カ. Are there any words that is it as カ?

Comment: The word for 'geometry' is 幾何学 (きかがく) - https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B9%BE%E4%BD%95%E5%AD%A6-50007

Comment: That's the one (幾何)! Thank you very much. Is it only one?

Comment: It appears some names of Chinese historical figures that use this character are read with か. For instance, 何晏 https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BD%95%E6%99%8F and 何休 https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BD%95%E4%BC%91

Comment: en wiktionary has categories for each character/reading combination, e.g. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese_terms_spelled_with_%E4%BD%95_read_as_%E3%81%8B , but apparently incomplete judging by current answers

Comment: Funnily, 幾何 apparently do not represent any idea of geometry. The word is actually a rare example of a Chinese-made science-name, with t͡ɕi xɤ apparently being a rendering of “geo-“ in Geometry (though disputed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that there are many more common uses of the 訓読み `なに` or `なん` for 何 when compared with the words which use the 音読み `カ`.

But here is one example: The word for 'geometry' is:

> 幾何学 (きかがく) - [definition](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B9%BE%E4%BD%95%E5%AD%A6-50007)

Although it also seems to appear in words like 如何せん (いかんせん) or 如何 (いかが), I don't think those are strictly standard usages of the readings but more of a jukujikun type (reading by meaning). For example, `い` is not a standard reading of the kanji 如 [(see here for details)](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjic/1438.html). Therefore I'm not sure that 如何 qualifies as a usage of the 音読み here.

There are probably more examples - I will check and edit in others if I find them.

Comment: 大辞林 also has 無何有{むかう}, as in 無何有{むかう}の郷{さと} or 無何有郷{むかうきょう} (「作為のない自然のままの世界。理想郷。ユートピア。」) I doubt these are very common, but 無何有 does pop up as an option when I type むかう on my iPad.

Answer (score 2):

According to kanshudo.com counts, 幾何 and its derivatives are the only words that can be encountered among the frequent lexicon. However, there is at least [誰何]{すいか}する “challenging (an unknown person); asking a person's identity” which is rare but still completely recognizable.

Of course, any (Classical) Chinese word can theoretically be a Japanese one read like this; from the 四字熟語 list at http://www.edrdg.org/projects/yojijukugo.html I find [無何之郷]{むかのきょう} [無何有郷]{むかゆうきょう}.